# bash.exe - entry point not found

Tags: cygwin

when trying to install cygwin, I keep getting this error message:

> the entry point
>   rl_filename_rewrite_hook could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library
>   cygreadline7.dll

Has anyone seen this before ?

Thanks

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: I have same error message but entry point ___locale_mb_cur_max

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same error with cygwin1.dll.  I checked in c:\cygwin\bin and noticed there were two files, cygwin1.dll and cygwin1.dll.new (possibly from a failed or aborted setup run?).  The ".new" version was in fact newer (and slightly larger) than the existing cygwin1.dll, so I replaced cygwin1.dll with cygwin1.dll.new, and ran setup again.  It completed with no errors.

Comment: I was having the described problem and found cygreadline7.dll.new; replacing cygreadline7.dll with it solved the problem. Previously I'd updated cygwin while bash was running so it hadn't been able to replace the file, but it looks like for some reason it hadn't completed upon rebooting as it's supposed to.

Comment: phenomenal solution; no way I would have found that on my own

Comment: you are amazing ! that worked like a charm. Cheers, fellow IT guy !

Answer (score 3):

First idea is to try reinstalling libreadline7 (or similarly named package) using the cygwin installer. Use the search field to enter readline to make it easier to find the right package.

Another option is that in the cygwin installer, change form Curr to Prev in order to switch to the previous-stable release. This means lots and lots of downloading and reinstalling. I anctually did manage to provoke my error into becoming a libreadline7 error, and switching to Prev at least got rid of the error messages. (Yay! Now bash, ssh server and git is working again! Back to work here then...)

Answer (score 1):

Please check your path in WINDOWS (advanced system properties) environment.  I found that C:\WinAVR\bin was coming before my cygwin path, so I moved that to the end, fixed my issue.

If you have multiple CYGWIN1.DLL files in your system, it definitely causes headaches if you're not careful.